# How do I access the TEB in PIN?

Tags: windows, winapi, pintool

In PIN's documentation it says this about `PIN_SafeCopy`:

> PIN_SafeCopy is used to copy the specified number of bytes from a
>   source memory region to a destination memory region. This function
>   guarantees safe return to the caller even if the source or destination
>   regions are inaccessible (entirely or partially). Use of this function
>   also guarantees that the tool reads or writes the values used by the
>   application. For example, on Windows, Pin replaces certain TEB fields
>   when running a tool's analysis code. If the tool accessed these fields
>   directly, it would see the modified values rather than the original
>   ones. Using PIN_SafeCopy() allows the tool to read or write the
>   application's values for these fields.

I'm trying to get the stack base of the current thread. Normally I would get it like this (if going directly through `FS`): `mov eax, FS:[0x04]`. Since I'm getting the old stack, and not the "new" one maintained by PIN (if I compare the `REG_ESP` from PIN with the current `ESP` they show different stacks) I tried to first get the linear address of the TEB with `mov eax, FS:[0x18]` and then use `PIN_SafeCopy` to read from this address + 0x04. However I only get 0x00000000. Any idea how I can do this? Also I suppose this makes it risky to use the Win API if it reads from such stale sources of data?